# i am getting a callback error when i want to fetch data from mongodb in my login form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback

At line 2

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
monmodel.findOne({PhoneNo: req.body.phone, Password: req.body.password}, function(err, user){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else if(user){
        res.redirect('/hydrometer');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Invalid');
    }
});
});
```

i need an alternative than the callback function

Comment: Do you compare clear-text passwords?

Comment: you can find it in the here [model_Model-findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using mongoose@7.5.3 where Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback, as pointed by Tobok in the comment.

You need to downgrade mongoose to 6.12.0 version. If you check the same doc for this version yo can see it still accepts the callback function: [Model.findOne v6.12.0](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne)